# convert int to const char* in order to write on file

Tags: c++, char, constants, int

I have the following code in C++ and I would like to convert a integer to a const char* in order to write on a file. I tried itoa or sstream functions but it's not working.

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");

int a = 5;

fputs (&a,pFile);
fclose (pFile);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful. I assume you'd want people to tell you more than "fix it", right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter to `fputs` is a `char*`, so the code you show is obviously incorrect.

You say `I tried itoa or sstream functions but it's not working.` but those *are* the solutions, and there's no reason for them not to work.

```
int a = 5;

//the C way
FILE* pFile = fopen("myfile.txt","w");
char buffer[12];
atoi(a, buffer, 10);
fputs(buffer, pFile); 
fclose (pFile);
//or
FILE* pFile = fopen("myfile.txt","w");
fprintf(pfile, "%d", a);
fclose(pfile);

//the C++ way
std::ofstream file("myfile.txt");
std::stringstream ss;
ss << a;
file << ss.str();
//or
std::ofstream file("myfile.txt");
file << a;
```

Comment: My error was that I was trying to manage both fputs and ofstream. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Don't cross the streams!"  Closest to `fputs` for `ofstream` is `ofstream::write(const char_type *_Str, streamsize _Count)`

Answer (score 1):

Try `itoa(a)` it converts an **i** nt **to**  **a** rray hence `itoa`

Comment: there's also the opposite `atoi` which is for an `array` to an `int`

Comment: I'm more a fan of `strtol` for the string-to-int (`long` really) route. It lets me set the numeric base, and I can set base 0 to mean "figure it out from the prefix" (which lets me parse `0x1234` and such). And it gives me a pointer to the character past the end of the number, where I can try to parse units.

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function. From [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/): "This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers."

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `fprintf`? Or `snprintf` and then `fputs` the result.

Comment: Get into the habit of using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Use type-casting. You can use [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/480568-convert-int-into-const-char-/)

Once in a string, you can use the c_str() member function to get a const char *